Does a touch spell have advantage when delivered by an invisible Familiar?
While, there is general consensus that the 2014 rules give the spell's attack roll advantage, 2024's Find Familiar wording has changed to

... when you cast a spell with a range of touch, your familiar can deliver the touch.

with some caveats and constraints. The Combat mechanics specify that

When a creature can’t see you, you have Advantage on attack rolls against it.

which is fairly straightforward, especially with regard to the Invisible condition except in the case of Touch ranged Spells, where

The spell’s effect originates on something the spellcaster must touch, as defined in the spell.

Similar topics have been addressed in questions like:

How does the Warlock's invocation Gaze of Two Minds interact with the Unseen rule?

How does the Warlock's invocation Gaze of Two Minds interact with a creature with the Invisible Condition?

Can a familiar maintain invisibility while delivering a touch spell?


where it seems generally clear that pertinent spellcasting mechanics are basically determined by the Warlock, rather than the proxy creature. However, Touch ranged spells seem like a special edge case, since they require the proxy to physically touch the target.
So, how does invisibility interact with attack mechanics when a familiar delivers Touch ranged spells?

No, the spell attack does not have advantage (RAW)
(This answer is just based on the rules as written in the 2024 PHB. I think it's kinda silly, but it's not the first silly interaction we've found in 2024 and it probably won't be the last. Please remember that downvotes are not meant to express disagreement—let me know how my answer could be improved.)
There are currently only two touch-ranged spells in the 2024 Players Handbook that call for spell attacks, and could thus possibly gain advantage from the Invisible condition. Those spells are:

Chill Touch
Shocking Grasp

(These both happen to be Wizard spells, but I did include all classes in my search. Shillelagh used to be touch-ranged in D&D 5e 2014, but its range is now self in 2024.)
Both spells are worded similarly:

Channeling the chill of the grave, make a melee spell attack against a target within reach. On a hit, …


Lightning springs from you to a creature that you try to touch. Make a melee spell attack against the target. On a hit, …

(Emphasis mine.)
Find Familiar's specific effect clearly changes the rules for choosing a spell target, allowing you to target a creature that's outside your reach but within reach for your familiar. But the 64000 GP Question is: Who makes the melee spell attack? Is it your familiar? Or is it you, the spellcaster?
It's still the spellcaster's attack
(For some prior discussion, see the accepted answer to Can a familiar maintain invisibility while delivering a touch spell?, which was linked in the question.)
I think we all agree that if the invisible familiar makes the spell attack, then the attack would certainly be made at advantage. But if it's the spellcaster, then the familiar's invisibility would be irrelevant.
There are two key elements in these spells:

A touch, as referenced in the rules for spell ranges and in the effect of Find Familiar.
A melee spell attack, as described in the effects of Chill Touch and Shocking Grasp.

Find Familiar's specific rule concerning “delivering the touch” overrides the general rules concerning spell ranges. As the Player's Handbook says,

The game also includes elements—class features, feats, weapon properties, spells, magic items, monster abilities, and the like—that sometimes contradict a general rule. When an exception and a general rule disagree, the exception wins.
— Exceptions Supersede General Rules (Emphasis mine)

But then there's the melee spell attack. The general rule is that the spellcaster makes the attack roll.

Some spells require the caster to make an attack roll to determine whether the spell hits a target.
— Spells: Effects (Emphasis mine)

And remember, spells do exactly what they say.

The effects of a spell are detailed after its duration entry. Those details present exactly what the spell does, which ignores mundane physical laws; …
— Ibid. (Emphasis mine)

So a mundane trifle like making a melee attack against a target you can't reach doesn't contradict that general rule.
If the attacker is going to change, we need one of two things:

Either a specific rule that overrides the general rule; or
A general rule saying that the creature “delivering the touch” is also the one to make the attack.

Regarding the first point, Find Familiar doesn't mention anything about attacks—only “the touch.” I'm not aware of any other specific rule that would apply here.
And regarding the second point, I'm not aware of any rule tying the melee spell attack in these two touch-ranged spells to “the touch,” nor of an attack being referred to as a “touch” anywhere else in the rules.
Besides this absence of a rule, I think there's some evidence that the game thinks of touches and attacks as separate things:

No other touch-ranged spells that target hostile creatures involve an attack. All the others require saving throws, but mostly Wisdom or Constitution saving throws to resist the effects, not Dexterity to avoid the touch.
This would indicate that simply touching a hostile creature is not contested in D&D 5e. Creatures can always touch each other in combat for free, but that generally has no game effect until a spell cares about it.
The new 2024 version of Inflict Wounds is especially interesting because it always has a negative effect, regardless of the saving throw result—the target still takes half damage on a save. This is strong evidence that the attack or saving throw isn't testing whether the touch succeeds—it's a separate thing.

Also, there are spells like Vampiric Touch that are not touch-ranged, but still involve melee spell attacks as part of their spell effect.
This is further evidence that there's no special relationship between touch range and melee spell attacks.


In the absence of a rule tying them together, the touch and the spell attack seem to be separate things—they just normally coincide when casting “by hand.” But Find Familiar only modifies the former.
Then, since it's the spellcaster and not the familiar making the attack roll, the familiar's Invisible condition wouldn't have any bearing on the roll. (This also implies that if the spellcaster were the invisible one, then their spell attack would be at advantage—even if delivered by a fully visible familiar.)
As an aside, I think this result is reasonable (if not narratively satisfying) given this accepted answer which says that, if the familiar isn't making an attack roll or casting a spell, delivering a touch wouldn't end an Invisibility spell affecting the familiar. If the spell attack were made with advantage, a spellcaster could cast Chill Touch and Shocking Grasp at advantage every turn just by having their invisible familiar in their square—I don't think Pact of the Chain was meant to be a Chill Touch/Shocking Grasp buff. (Not that Pact of the Chain needs to be nerfed, but that feels cheesy.)
Rules as intended?
Personally, I think this result is silly. Luckily, it's also pretty niche—at least until WotC publishes a more powerful touch-ranged spell involving a melee spell attack for D&D 5e 2024.
Assuming it didn't lead to shenanigans, I'd probably introduce a house rule at my table that the familiar does deliver the attack (using the spellcaster's spell attack modifier). So then a familiar under the effect of Invisibility would have advantage on the attack roll, but would also lose the Invisible condition. I think that would be the “rules as intended,” or at least the “rules as fun.”

Oh, hah, I see that OP wrote the accepted answer to that question. :D

I don't think Pact of the Chain was meant to be a Chill Touch/Shocking Grasp buff - so what if it was? It just makes it slightly less of a sacrifice vs. Eldritch Blast.  As you found, there are no higher-level touch attack-roll spells anymore, so only a balance concern for characters still using 2014 versions of spells like Contagion or upcast Inflict Wounds.  In situations where the debuff from the cantrips is really valuable, then it just seems like a nice bonus.

@Tarod I wrote a response earlier as a comment, but I've included my reasoning in the answer and deleted that comment. Tl;dr: I don't know of a rule that says the attack in the spell effect is the touch.

@PeterCordes I don't think Pact of the Chain needs balancing. It's more that getting advantage from being invisible and getting to stay invisible is cheesy. (Greater Invisibility is two levels higher than Invisibility after all.) It's cute for now, until WotC publishes a more powerful touch-ranged melee spell. It has to fall one way or the other—either the familiar is attacking or it isn't—and I don't see rules support to say the familiar is the one making the attack.

Yeah, I actually agree with that, that it's cheesy.  I hadn't thought through the question of whether they remain invisible, but having looked at the Q&A you linked, I don't find the OP's argument there totally convincing.  The title here only asks if they have advantage from being invisible, which makes narrative sense at least.

@PeterCordes, I updated the argument to include additional considerations. RAW, the familiar only delivers the PCs spell, so the PC is responsible for the attack roll. It may be dissatisfying, but that's the RAW interpretation. It's only when you consider in tandem with this question that it appears incongruous.

@nonymous: This is one of those corner-case rules interactions where it would be very reasonable for the DM to make a ruling on the grounds that RAW doesn't make narrative sense and probably didn't consider this interaction.  (If you can't make an RAW argument for an imp's invisibility ending when it delivers an attack-roll, e.g. that it's making the attack roll with the master's modifier.  In 2014 at least, there was an invocation that buffed familiars' regular attacks to get the master's bonus, I think voice of the chain master, so maybe casting a spell through them is similar...)

"And finally, when another creature delivers an attack for you, I believe the rules are usually explicit that, e.g., the attack uses your attack modifier." => I don't see the relevance, just because a Familiar uses their owner's attack modifier doesn't mean that it's not the Familiar attacking. (Which doesn't mean the Familiar is attacking, just that the conclusion doesn't follow)

@MatthieuM. My point is just that I believe there's usually language like "This attack is made using the spellcaster's spell attack modifier" or similar when someone else attacks for you. That language is not present in any of the rules relevant to familiars delivering touches, which is further (indirect) evidence that it's still the spellcaster making the attack.

@MatthieuM. It's not core to my argument, just one more piece of evidence. The important part is that there are no rules affecting the attack, and no rules that actually tie the attack to the touch—just flavor.

I think I can clean that section up a bit. I have a bad habit of presenting evidence without first motivating why it's relevant.

@MatthieuM. I reorganized and cleaned up my argument a bit, and I actually decided to drop that part you mentioned. It was kind of weak anyway.

@ChrisBouchard: I like the new section/wording!

If it is the spellcaster that delivers the attack & not the familiar, doesn't that imply that if the spellcaster is not visible to the target then they DO get advantage, regardless of whether the familar is visible or invisible?

@DwayneTheVrock There's a lot to unpack in there, but I would think yes. I mentioned the spellcaster having the Invisible condition in the answer, and I imagine the same reasoning would apply to being hidden in general. But then also, if the spellcaster couldn't see the target (say they were on opposite sides of a wall) then the attack would also have disadvantage, which would cancel out. Another question would be if half or three-quarters cover would apply—I'd guess that it would, but I haven't read those rules carefully.

Yes, Advantage applies
If the Familiar is still invisible when delivering the touch, then it keeps the Advantage and the Invisible condition is lost.
The you in the Unseen Attackers and Targets rule is referring to whatever creature is Invisible / can't be seen. In this case it is your familiar, and it would have advantage even though it uses your your spellcasting ability modifier and your Proficiency Bonus.

Invisible [Condition]
While you have the Invisible condition, you
experience the following effects.
[...]
Attacks Affected. Attack rolls against you have Disadvantage, and your
attack rolls have Advantage. If a creature can somehow see you, you
don’t gain this benefit against that creature.

Basically, an attack is an attack, no matter the range. Spells with Range: Touch that involve attacks require the caster to make a melee spell attack against the target, but the physical touch (i.e., the attack) will be delivered by the Familiar. Examples of such spells include Chill Touch and Shocking Grasp.
The same would apply if the caster delivers the touch (the attack) themselves without using the Familiar.
Invisibility is lost
The spell states:

A creature you touch has the Invisible condition until the spell ends.
The spell ends early immediately after the target makes an attack
roll, deals damage, or casts a spell.

Due to the emphasized reason, the Familiar would lose the Invisible condition because it is delivering something that qualifies as an attack.
Addendum based on comments
Master and the Familiar are invisible
In a hypothetical scenario where both the Master and the Familiar are invisible, each would lose the Invisible condition for different reasons:

The Master, because they cast a spell.
The Familiar, for the reasons mentioned above.

Relation between Touch and the melee spell attack
Touch is defined as follows in the rules:

Touch. The spell's effect originates on something the spellcaster must
touch, as defined in the spell.

This answer is based on the interpretation that to achieve a successful physical touch to trigger the spell's effect, a successful melee spell attack roll is required (when the spell says so), and both things are interconnected. It's similar to how swinging a melee weapon involves an attack roll to finally hit a creature.
A weird scenario using a different ruling
If the Master had the Invisible condition and were in a different room than the Familiar, while the Familiar remained visible, physical attacks delivered by the Familiar would have Advantage, which feels odd.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
